# FosUserBundle My custom User Entity does not Implement \ArrayAccess

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have made the following FormType in order to edit the User profile:

```
namespace AppUserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;

class UserProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //$builder->addViewTransformer($this->purifierTransformer);
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('surname');
        $builder->add('description',TextareaType::class);
    }

//  public function getParent()
//  {
//      return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType';
//  }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    // For Symfony 2.x
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

And I have set it as a service like that:

```
  app_user.user_profile_form:
    class: AppUserBundle\Form\Type
    tags:
      - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

And the following configs in `config.yml`:

```
fos_user:
  ...
  profile:
    form:
      type: AppUserBundle\Form\Type\UserProfileFormType
```

As I have seen on [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html) I can override completely the form by just not overriding the `getParent()` method. As documentations says:

> If you don't want to reuse the fields added in FOSUserBundle by default, you can omit the getParent method and configure all fields yourself.

But I get the following error:

> Cannot read index "name" from object of type "AppUserBundle\Entity\User" because it doesn't implement \ArrayAccess.

Please keep in mind that the `AppUserBundle\Entity\User` has the following code:

```
namespace AppUserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_image", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $userImage;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The surname is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The surname is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=1024, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    public function setUserImage($imagepath)
    {
        $this->userImage=$imagepath;
    }

    public function functiongetUserImage()
    {
        return $this->userImage;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name=strip_tags($name);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->surname=strip_tags($surname);
    }

    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description=$description;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

very old but as i were also stuck on this i hope to help somebody. You have to tell Symfony that you are using your custom Registration Form with your User class by adding the following function

```
 $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'YourBundle\Entity\User',
    ));
```